# Why use WebMatrix Facebook helpers verus just using facebook generator?

Tags: facebook, html-helper, webmatrix

I am wondering why would you use the html helper for something like the [like button](http://facebookhelper.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home)

then using the generator from [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use the Twitter helper, or the Gravatar helper for that matter? Or any helper?

WebMatrix is targeted at an audience of learners. This group is barely assumed to know HTML (although I realise that description covers a lot of experienced Web Forms developers too), so providing a reasonably consistent set of APIs to help make use of social networking widgets makes sense to me. It means that the learner can have Twitter feeds and Like buttons on their first site in a few seconds, rather than having to trawl all over the Internet to find out how these things are done, and then potentially getting confused by the developer material offered by these sites. If they achieve a degree of success early on, they will more likely persist with the framework.

Comment: What Mike said. Also, we'll continue to update the helpers so as Twitter or whoever changes or adds new things, we will too. This follows the ideas of NuGet and making it so people don't have to do all the dirty work (installing, updating, learning, etc) to use these things.